# EF Core name mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I've been trying to figure out how to do the following (although my research did not help): I have the these three classes:

```
public abstract class Classifier
{
    public int ClassifierId { get; set; }
    public string ClassifierName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}

public class ManualClassifier : Classifier
{
    public int ManualClassifierId { get; set; }
    public string user_name { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}

public class ToolClassifier : Classifier
{
    public int ToolId { get; set; }
    public string ToolName { get; set; }    
}
```

Both the ManualClassifier and ToolClassifer  inherit from Classifier. I'm using EF Core to map this to a database but the question is the following: I've already searched a bit and I must make use of a descriminator which basically is an implicitly created column that will say the type of, in this case, classifier. So far so good. The issue arises when I have a property called ManualClassifierId as well as a ToolId. I want this two properties to map to the ClassifierId property. So in the table representing the entity Classifier, the ClassifierId property will either be the ManualClassifierId or the ToolId.
How can I achieve this mapping? Also, this solution would mean that both child classes would both have empty fileds in the tables (due to inheriting the three properties from the Classifier class). Is there a better solution? Perhaps just erase the Id's from both child classes a let them inherit the parent one?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance that should tell you everything needed. Short answer, you can either make the tool classifier and manual classifier have their own table, or have 1 extended table. It also walks you through how to make the classifiers share a column.

Answer (score 1):

To use the same column name in both classes, you can add a `Column` attribute to both properties. Then they will both use that column name in the database. See [ColumnAttribute(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute.-ctor?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute.%2523ctor)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0#system-componentmodel-dataannotations-schema-columnattribute-ctor(system-string)).

Use it like this:

```
public class ManualClassifier : Classifier
{
    [Column(Name="ClassifierId")]
    public int ManualClassifierId { get; set; }
...........
}
```

Do the same with `ToolId`.